# Is it allowed to ask an automatically deleted question again?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[A question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294301/whats-the-difference-between-difficulty-settings) regarding difficulty settings in Deus Ex was deleted due to downvotes. The question wasn't against the rules, and in itself was worthwhile.
Is it allowed to resubmit a question that was deleted solely because of downvotes?

[image]

Comment: I forgot that deleted questions aren't permanently removed and can be restored, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294301/whats-the-difference-between-difficulty-settings) (Viewable to post owner, 10k users, and mods, as usual.). The problem with how you asked it the first time was that you really didn't *ask* much. You had the title, and then a screenshot of the difficulty settings, and that was it. While I understand that sometimes there's not a lot more to ask than what you have in the title, you really should make an effort to at least expand on it somewhat.

There's nothing stopping you from trying to ask it again, but there's also nothing stopping the community at large from treating it the same way if you make no effort to improve it, especially now that they're effectively aware of your plans to post the same thing again.  (It's also then technically a duplicate, which we kinda frown upon.)

The more preferred course of action is for you to improve the current post and then vote to undelete it, but this does require 2 10K+ members of the community to also vote to undelete the post, so you're going to have to  make very sure it's up to the Arqade community's standards if you're wanting to convince people it's worth that.

Comment: Personally I consider extra information as superfluous and clutter in this case, but I'll try finding something valuable to add.

Comment: @user598527 maybe try adding what you expect would be different across the difficulties.  For example: "Do you have less damage resistance on a higher difficulty? Do items appear less on harder difficulties?"  I'm unfamiliar with the game itself, so I don't know if my examples would apply, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: @user598527 The downvote button tooltip reads *"This question does not show any research effort; It's unclear or not useful"*. A starting point would be to expand on your research you took to find out yourself before asking, & explain why you want this information - why is it useful to know?

Comment: @Robotnik: I think that difficulty settings are interesting by definition. I have researched a lot though and never found a definitive answer.

Comment: @user598527 - don't tell *me*, put it in your question body :-)